# Litho Radio Group container

Tags: android, litho

I followed the checkbox example on Litho guide and built a similar implementation for a radio button:

```
@LayoutSpec
object CRadioSpec {

    @OnCreateLayout
    fun onCreateLayout(
        c: ComponentContext,
        @Prop value: String,
        @State isChecked: Boolean
    ): Component? {
        return Column.create(c)
            .alignContent(YogaAlign.CENTER)
            .widthDip(20F)
            .child(
                Image.create(c)
                    .drawableRes(
                        if (isChecked) R.drawable.ic_checkbox_on
                        else R.drawable.ic_checkbox_off)
                    .clickHandler(CRadio.onCheckboxClicked(c))
            )
            .child(
                Text.create(c)
                    .alignment(TextAlignment.CENTER)
                    .alignSelf(YogaAlign.CENTER)
                    .widthDip(20F)
                    .text(value)
                    .build()
            )
            .build()
    }

    @OnCreateInitialState
    fun onCreateInitialState(
        c: ComponentContext?,
        isChecked: StateValue<Boolean?>,
        @Prop initChecked: Boolean
    ) {
        isChecked.set(initChecked)
    }

    @OnUpdateState
    fun updateCheckboxState(isChecked: StateValue<Boolean?>) {
         isChecked.get()?.let {
             isChecked.set(it.not())
         }
    }

    @OnUpdateState
    fun updateCheckbox(isChecked: StateValue<Boolean?>) {
        isChecked.get()?.let {
            isChecked.set(it.not())
        }

    }

    @OnEvent(ClickEvent::class)
    fun onCheckboxClicked(c: ComponentContext?) {
        CRadio.updateCheckbox(c)
    }
}
```

However I believe this is to be wrapped inside a parent in order to get multiple radio boxes and state has to be managed from parent. As has been mentioned in the docs:

> Let’s take the example of a list of radio buttons, where you cannot
>   have multiple items checked at the same time. The state of all the
>   radio buttons depends on whether other items get clicked and checked.
>   Instead of making all the radio buttons stateful, you should keep the
>   state of what item is clicked in the parent and propagate that
>   information top-down to the children through props.

[Link](https://fblitho.com/docs/best-practices)

I did quite a bit of searching but I am not able to find anything relevant. I also checked the Implementation of Spinner Component, but cant get to a good implementation. It would be a great help, if I can be guided to a concrete example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a Radio group and manage state from there, that is the parent:

Here is one way of doing it:

```
@LayoutSpec
object CrgSpec {
    @OnCreateLayout
    fun onCreateLayout(
        c: ComponentContext,
        @Prop viewModel: ViewModel,
        @State fields: ArrayList<RadioItem>,
        @Prop parentId: String
    ): Component? {
        val row =
            Row.create(c)
                .alignItems(YogaAlign.CENTER)
                .alignContent(YogaAlign.SPACE_AROUND)
                .flexGrow(1F)
                .wrap(YogaWrap.WRAP)
        fields.forEach { item ->
            row.child(
                CRadio.create(c)
                    .value(item.text)
                    .clickHandler(Crg.onClicked(c, item.id, item.text))
                    .isChecked(item.isChecked)
                    .id(item.id)
                    .build()
            )
        }
        val column = Column.create(c)
            .paddingDip(YogaEdge.TOP, 20F)
            .child(row.build())
        return column.child(
            TextInput.create(c)
                //.visibleHandler()
                .backgroundRes(R.drawable.edit_text_bg)
                .build()
        ).build()
    }

    @OnCreateInitialState
    fun onCreateInitialState(
        c: ComponentContext?,
        fields: StateValue<ArrayList<RadioItem>>,
        @Prop initChecked: ArrayList<RadioItem>
    ) {
        fields.set(initChecked)
    }

    @OnUpdateState
    fun updateCheckboxState(
        fields: StateValue<ArrayList<RadioItem>>,
        @Param id: String
    ) {
        fields.get()?.let { radioItem ->
            radioItem.forEach {
                it.isChecked = it.id == id
            }
            fields.set(radioItem)
        }
    }


    @OnUpdateState
    fun updateCheckbox(
        fields: StateValue<ArrayList<RadioItem>>,
        @Param id: String
    ) {
        fields.get()?.let { radioItem ->
            radioItem.forEach {
                it.isChecked = it.id == id
            }
            fields.set(radioItem)
        }
    }

    @OnEvent(ClickEvent::class)
    fun onClicked(
        c: ComponentContext?,
        @Prop viewModel: ViewModel,
        @Param id: String,
        @Prop parentId: String,
        @Param itemValue: String
    ) {
        Timber.d("id is: $id")
        CirclesRadioGroup.updateCheckbox(c, id)
        viewModel.onRadioUpdate(
            id,
            parentId,
            itemValue
        )
    }
}
```

Refrences:

- https://jayrambhia.com/blog/android-litho-state
- https://fblitho.com/docs/state
- https://fblitho.com/docs/best-practices

Bonus:- This is also a very nice example of how you would get user action callbacks in your view model and a compact example of a server driven UI on Android.